# TInymce file upload

Tags: file, file-upload, tinymce

I have problem with uploading file (not image) in tinymce.

```
plugins: [
    'advlist', 'autolink', 'link', 'image', 'lists', 'charmap', 'preview', 'anchor', 'pagebreak',
    'searchreplace', 'wordcount', 'visualblocks', 'visualchars', 'code', 'fullscreen', 'insertdatetime',
    'media', 'table', 'emoticons', 'template', 'help',
],
toolbar: 'undo redo | styles | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | ' +
    'bullist numlist outdent indent | insert file link image  | print preview media fullscreen | ' +
    'forecolor backcolor emoticons | help',
```

here my plugins
there are only image and media upload buttons but I wanted to files like pdf. Who can help me